# How can I turn a graph into circles?

Tags: calculus, physics

Hi everyone this question might take a little bit to explain

I want to model the speed of a roller-coaster carriage at the bottom of a drop, accounting for friction. I'm trying to do this defining a function $f(x)$ that when graphed out at a certain interval draws a drop.

Maybe like this for example:

[image: a graph of f(x) that looks a bit like a roller-coaster drop at a certain interval]

Where between approximately $x= -1$ and $x = 2/5$ is how my roller-coaster drop looks.

To find the speed not accounting for friction I can use simple energy conservation equations. To find the energy lost to friction though it is a bit harder.

I need to find the normal forces times the coefficient of friction. (Coefficient of friction is just a value between $0$ and $1$ defining how rough a surface is). This is possible using derivatives and integrals. I also need to know though the forces changing the direction of the carriage. To do this I think I would have to calculate the force due to circular motion at every point on the function.

To do that though I would somehow have to connect circles to how to function is changing over time.

So for example at a point where there is little change in the function the circle radius would be very big:

[image]

And where there is a big change the radius would be very small:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea you can do this? So for a function $f(x)$ there is a corresponding function $g(x)$ that gives the radius of a circle a point $x$

Comment: Is it realistic to have the diameter of the wheels variable in time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cartesian form, for a plane curve, the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Graph_of_a_function) is given by

$$\kappa(x)=\frac{|f''(x)|}{\left(1+[f'(x)]^2\right)^\frac 32}$$

then the radius of the [osculating circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) is given by

$$g(x)=\frac1 {\kappa(x)}=\frac{\left(1+[f'(x)]^2\right)^\frac 32}{|f''(x)|}$$

Comment: But you need also to position the center...

Comment: @JeanMarie Maybe I'm wrong but in this case it seems that the OP is asking how to evaluate the centipetal acceleration by $\frac{v^2}R$ therefore we need only $R$ at a certain point.

Comment: @JeanMarie Please let me know if now it is clear! Thanks, bye